# TypeScript Object Factory

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build an object factory in TypeScript where the objects generated must have a common base type, but I haven't figured out how to encode it properly.

Here's my current attempt which is incorrect because TypeScript says T is not guaranteed to be of type Base.

```
class Base {
    constructor() {}
}


class User extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}

class Post extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}

function buildObject<T extends Base>(type: typeof Base): T {
    return new type()
}
```

I thought I could just create a new type like `type BaseInstance<T> = T extends Base` to use here instead:

```
function buildObject<T>(type: typeof BaseInstance<T>): BaseInstance<T> {
    return new type()
}
```

But this construct `type BaseInstance<T> = T extends Base` is invalid.

Comment: Use `type: new() => T` instead of `type: typeof Base` as `buildObject ` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining a type BaseConstructor which can be called via the `new` keyword and return an instance of Base. Your classes Base, User, and Post all fulfill this type definition.

```
type BaseConstructor<T extends Base> = new() => T;

function buildObject<T extends Base>(type: BaseConstructor<T>): T {
    return new type();
}

const myObj: Post = buildObject(Post);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ0PWAewHYQBcAnAV2AOyIAoBKFAX1UdVVEhgFUIEjoEAPAglwATGPG4p0mHPmJkK1OmkyroEEgAcetaRkbM2UaAAVshPoOFi4iKatmFS5SrXtqMG7Ur3QDLAgBPbVtuAGE8JwVKAB4AFUshUXFEAD5oAF5oXAQAd2g3DPS4gG4WADMSXHIASzxoACMSGpARAHkGgCsEcnjE6xTuVKog7QAuUIQIuWdFeNSaCYSVTCIEAhIiXGy86FGEXUNIgmgAW0COzomzCyymlvaunoIqG4IaEqA)